# text_mn in Radare2 --> Meaning?

Tags: radare2, functions

I compiled some source code and extracted functions with Radare2 (afj).

Often I get a function with "sym..text_mn" function name/ symbol.

The other functions are named correctly. What does this symbol mean/ stand for?

Answer (score 1):

This is the symbol that marks the start/beginning of section named `.text_mn`. The char for underscore could be different char in the binary, I sometimes see that for '$'.

It might be that the address is the same as a function might have and for some reason the function did not get analyzed correctly.

For most cases you should just get two labels, one for function name and one for section, pointing to the same address.